# Azure Pipelines terraform init -backend-config throwing exit code 127

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

Have a simple pipeline for terraform planning and deployment

Getting an error (exit code 127) when running a terraform init in my pipeline via a template

Here's the template that holds the init steps

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Terraform Init'
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      script: |
        set -euo pipefail
        
        echo "Initialize"
        terraform init \
            -input=false \
            -backend-config="resource_group_name=${TF_STORAGE_RG}" \ 
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT}" \
            -backend-config="container_name=${TF_STORAGE_BLOB_CONTAINER}" \
            -backend-config="key=${TF_STORAGE_BLOB_NAME}" 
    
     
        terraform validate
    
       
        terraform -v
        terraform providers
```

I have the values stored in a variable group accessible to the pipeline

but I'm getting the error

```
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
/home/vsts/work/_temp/d3a0a3ba-04aa-4b39-8c4a-78045790fbe4.sh: line 8: -backend-config=storage_account_name="statebucket": command not found
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
Finishing: Terraform Init
```

Struggling to understand why it's throwing a 'command not found' error at me. Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be a YAML/shell interpreter formatting issue. The error message also conflicts with the provided YAML as the string quotes appear at different locations. Is the question content fully accurate?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for replying. The line 8 refers to the line number within the script as opposed to the overall YAML. I'm also confused as to why it would throw that error for line 8 without erroring out in line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space at the end of the line following the "\" after ${TF_STORAGE_RG}. See below - if I run a sed to remove the space at the end of the line, the "command not found" error goes away.  I get a different error, but that's a different issue.

```
$ cat doit.sh
export TF_STORAGE_RG=a
export TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=b
export TF_STORAGE_BLOB_CONTAINER=c
export TF_STORAGE_BLOB_NAME=d

terraform init \
        -input=false \
        -backend-config="resource_group_name=${TF_STORAGE_RG}" \
        -backend-config="storage_account_name=${TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT}" \
        -backend-config="container_name=${TF_STORAGE_BLOB_CONTAINER}" \
        -backend-config="key=${TF_STORAGE_BLOB_NAME}"

$ ./doit.sh
Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?
./doit.sh: line 10: -backend-config=storage_account_name=b: command not found

$ sed -i 's/ $//g' doit.sh
$ ./doit.sh

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "b": storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: Invalid input: autorest/validation: validation failed: parameter=accountName constraint=MinLength value="b" details: value length must be greater than or equal to 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. Appreciate the sed snippet, will keep that in mind going forward if ever run into another issue like this.

Comment: Glad it helped.  This one is probably a little more useful as it removes all trailing whitespace (not just one space, like the original):  `sed -i 's/\s\+$//g' doit.sh`